# Can't retrieve JSONObject from my rest api

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, json

So I recently moved from Jersey 1.x to 2.x and after a long list of problems finaly got it working. But whenever I try to reach a resource which returns a JSONObject I get problems. First of, here is my example method:

```
@GET
@Path("/foobar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject print2() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("hi", 22);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Now if I use Jettison 1.3.8 for my JSONObject, I get the following if I try to reach this resource:

```
{"escapeForwardSlashAlways":true}
```

Not sure whats going on there. Then I tried some older versions of Jettison and also the org.json but these gives me this issue instead:

```
No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

Not sure why I get these problems when this kind of method worked fine for me on Jersey 1.x.

Comment: Do you use jackson for handling json serialization and vise versa?

Comment: i also got struck in this, using jersey 1.x i was able to return the jsonobect. But in jersey 2.x i am getting escapeForwardSlashAlways error. i cannot set the values in pogo to return the response, because the response will have nested jsonobject and jsonarray ? why is this working in jersey 1.x and not in 2.x ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Servlet 3.0 and above, the following example might help you to setup your environment to work with JSON data:

1. Dependency: if you are using Maven you need the following dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.23.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

If you are not using Maven, you need to add the correponding jars into your classpath.

2. Define POJOs to contain the data you want to serialize to JSON, for example,

   ```
   public class User {
      private String username;
      private String email;

      // getters + setters
   }
   ```
3. Modify your resource method accordingly:

   ```
   @GET
   @Path("/foobar")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public User print2() {
       User jsonObject = new User();
       jsonObject.setUsername("Me");
       jsonObject.setEmail("my@email.com");
       return jsonObject;
   }
   ```

Package and deploy, and the output should be:

> {
>       "username": "Me",
>       "email": "my@email.com"
>   }

Note: This example is deployed and works on Tomcat 8.5.5.

Comment: I had the same issue - {"escapeForwardSlashAlways":true}. I got JSON object in string simply by doing a  Jsonobject.toString()

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue, and eventually [Jersey's bookmark exmple](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/bookmark/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/bookmark/resource/UserResource.java) helped.

The problem is that your Jersey has no serializer for `JSONObject` and it tries to use BeanSerializer instead. Jettison JSONObject has only one public getter (`isEscapeForwardSlashAlways`) and `org.json.JSONObject` has no getters at all so `BeanSerializer` cannot be applied.

The solution is for (jettison json object):

1. Add dependency jersey-media-json-jettison:

> ```
> <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
>      <version>2.26</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Register the jettison feature declaratively in your web.xml

> ```
> <init-param>
>      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
>      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jettison.JettisonFeature</param-value>
> <init-param>
> ```

3. Or programmatically in your application:

> ```
> @ApplicationPath("/")
> public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
>      public MyApplication() {
>           registerClasses(UsersResource.class);
>           register(new JettisonFeature());
>      }
> }
> ```

web.xml:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
     <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookmark.MyApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Perhaps org.json.JSONObject has such serializer feature for Jersey too, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to allow the Response to convert your object to JSON.  This gives the added benefit of adding the HTTP code as well. So you can return a 400, 404, 500 etc. and still send back a JSON response that can be acted upon by your JS.  You should be able to drop your JSONObject in there since it's basically just extended Map - or any object for that matter.

```
@GET
@Path("/foobar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response print2() {
    User jsonObject = new User();
    jsonObject.setUsername("Me");
    jsonObject.setEmail("my@email.com");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonObject).build());
}
```